# rails model association using has_many: through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, has-many-through

i have a lessons table and a tags table. i associate both of the them using a has_many :through relationship and my middle table is tags_relationship.rb

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :desc, :content, :tag_name
  belongs_to :user

  has_many  :tag_relationships
  has_many  :tags, :through => :tag_relationships
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :tag_relationships
  has_many :lessons, :through => :tag_relationships
end
```

in one of my views, im trying to create a a virtual attribute. i have...

```
    <div class="tags">
        <%= f.label :tag_name, "Tags" %>
        <%= f.text_field :tag_name, data: { autocomplete_source: tags_path} %>
    </div>
```

but my lessons table doesn't have that attribute, tag_name, so it calls my method instead

```
    def tag_name
       ????????
    end

    def tag_name=(name)
        self.tag = Tag.find_or_initialize_by_name(name) if name.present?
    end
```

however im not sure what to put inside the ????????. im trying to refer the :name attribute inside my tags table.

back then i used a has_many and belongs_to relationship. my lesson belonged to a tag (which was wrong) but i was able to write...

```
tag.name
```

and it worked. but since its a has_many :through now, im not sure. i tried using tags.name, Lessons.tags.name, etc but i cant seem to get it to work. how can i refer to the tags table name attribute? thank you

Comment: Since you have a many to many relationship, it seems that you need to decide which one of all `tags` of a `lesson` the name should be.

Comment: im sorry but could you clarify? im not really sure what you meant by that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologize for my bad english.

When your `Lesson` was belonged to `Tag` lesson had only one `tag`, so your code was right. But now `Lesson` has many `Tag`s, and it is collection (array in simple words). So, your setter must be more complex:

```
def tag_names=(names)
  names = if names.kind_of? String
    names.split(',').map{|name| name.strip!; name.length > 0 ? name : nil}.compact
  else
    names
  end

  current_names = self.tags.map(&:name) # names of current tags
  not_added = names - current_names # names of new tags
  for_remove = current_names - names # names of tags that well be removed

  # remove tags
  self.tags.delete(self.tags.where(:name => for_remove))
  # adding new
  not_added.each do |name|
    self.tags << Tag.where(:name => name).first || Tag.new(:name => name)
  end
end
```

And getter method should be like this:

```
def tag_names
  self.tags.map(&:name)
end
```

BTW, finders like `find_by_name` are deprecated. You must use `where`.

Comment: thanks for the response. ummmm what about my getter though? its still throwing an error, where i put the ??????.

Comment: i would have thought tags.try(:name) would work but i guess not

Comment: Just updated my answer. `tags` is not a simple object. It is a Collection of Objects. So, it hasn't `name` method. But this metod have all it's elements

Comment: hmmm it still gives an error. is it possible if i chat with you really quickly?

Comment: thank you! let me see how this chat thing works. usually it gives the option after a few more comments

Comment: ah snap, i think you need 20 points for it to happen haha. hmm my skype doesnt always work. maybe we can try commenting a bit more?
quick question, i was trying to fix this myself and then i thought of changing it to instead of has_many: through to......has_many_and_belongs to many. would your code still work for that?

Comment: i can try changing it back to has_many: through. i decided to change it cause i didnt need additional attributes in my join table

Comment: Yes of course. The difference between `has_many :through` and `has_and_belongs_to_many` is in acessibility of glue table. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html -- here is good documentation about associations. But I haven't tested this code. So can you publish throwed exception?

Comment: oh i see. hmmmm. as of right now, it throws undefined method `tag_name'. let me change it back to has many : through. i can change it back in like 2 mins

Comment: =) You haven't got a `tag_name` method because you have MANY tags. So, method is `tag_names` and returns an `Array` of names of tags atached to your lesson.

Comment: oh wait okay, i just changed it back to has_many :through. sorry for delay and confusion! let me try it...

Comment: oh okay nice. good progress! now my text_field just populates with a []

Comment: It's good. It means that your `Lesson` hasn't got any tags (method returns empty array). To use result of this method in text field you need to join it into string: `tag_names.join(', ')`

Comment: hmm where exactly would i join them? i tried doing it in my view but i dont think thats correct haha.

i get the error 'undefined method `-' for "electric, pokemon, ":String' im thinking that join would probably fix it

Comment: but on a positive note...i fixed my jquery autocomplete! it still works. i was so scared if it would break because it took so long to do it, and im still not totally sure how it works but...i got it to work!

Comment: Where have you got error with undefined method `-`? In your view or in model in `tag_names=`?
You can add helper method `tag_names_string(lesson)` in your `LessonsHelper` and return `lesson.tag_names.join(', ')` from it.

Comment: hmmm it seems to come from

app/models/lesson.rb:22:in `tag_names='
app/controllers/lessons_controller.rb:11:in `create'

Comment: i got an idea how we could chat haha

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10296/discussion-between-crystal-and-george-vinogradov)